# How to show that that not every element has an inverse

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I just showed that the operation $ (a, b) \cdot (c, d) = (ac, bc+d) $ on the set $ \{(x,y) \in \Bbb R\times \Bbb R \mid x \neq 0 \} $ forms a group.

I'm now looking to determine if the same operation but on $\Bbb R\times \Bbb R$ is an operation. I know it isn't because not every element will have an inverse (when $x=0$, its inverse $1/x$ will be undefined) but I'm wondering if that's not quite sufficient because the definition of an inverse in this sense would be

> $\forall (x,y) \in \Bbb R\times \Bbb R \exists (x^{-1}, y^{-1})$ such that  $(x, y) \cdot (x^{-1}, y^{-1})=(e_1, e_2)$
>   and $(x^{-1}, y^{-1}) \cdot (x, y)=(e_1, e_2) $

So the negation of that would be

> $ \exists (x, y) \in \Bbb R\times \Bbb R$ such that $\forall (x^{-1}, y^{-1}) \in \Bbb R\times \Bbb R$,  $(x, y) \cdot (x^{-1}, y^{-1}) \neq (e_1, e_2)$ or $(x^{-1}, y^{-1}) \cdot (x, y) \neq (e_1, e_2) $

So my question is basically how do I show that FOR EVERY possible inverse that an element multiplied by the inverse doesn't equal the identity element? Does that make sense? Also, I apologize for any errors here; I'm trying to do this on the app for the first time and am new to math exchange.

Comment: Just to clarify:  the question is "show that there is some pair of  real numbers $(a,b)$ (where a ≠ 0) such that we can not solve $(ac,bc+d)=(1,0)$ (where we'd like (c,d) to be another pair of real numbers)", is that correct?

Comment: To emphasize:  I don't see the difficulty in finding (c,d).  As a≠0, we can take $c = \frac 1a$.  Then just take $d=-bc$. But perhaps I am not understanding the question.

Comment: Does the answer below answer your question because I'm not understanding what you're saying

Comment: No...it doesn't.  I thought you wanted to know if this defined a group operation. to do that you need to find inverses.  That's easy for (a,b) if a≠0 but it is not possible if a = 0 .  (you would need 0*c = 1)

Comment: From your comments to the posted solution I now deduce that you are asking the following "I have a group operation on $\mathbb R^2 $ at least if you remove all the points with first coordinate $0$. Can I extend that to a group operation on all of  $\mathbb R^2 $ ?"  The answer to that question is No.

Comment: Exactly. And I knew that but wasn't exactly sure how to show it

Comment: Ok, good.  To show that, take a point $(0,b)$.  Suppose it had an inverse, let's call it $(c,d)$.  What would that mean? Well, it would mean $(0*c,b*c+d)=(1,0)$.  That's two equations that need to be solved simultaneously:  $0*c=1\;and\;bc+d=0$. the second usually has lots of solutions, but it doesn't matter because the first equation is impossible.

Comment: Yes, that's what coldnumber described below; thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be an operation on a set, $\ast$ does not need to have inverses. It only needs to have closure, because an operation is a map  $\ast: S\times S \to S$. As long as you have closure, you have a map and hence an operation.

That said, that operation does not have inverses if you don't exclude the $0=x$ case.

To show this, you don't have to test every specific real number pair; you can just use an arbitrary pair of real numbers.

First, you find the element that you claim doesn't have an inverse; you said this was when the first coordinate $x$ was $0$, so let's use $(0,y)$, where $y\in \Bbb R$.

Then for any $(a,b) \in \Bbb R \times \Bbb R$ we have $$ (a,b)(0,y)=(0a, b0+y)=(0,y)\neq (1,0)$$

This shows that no element of $\Bbb R \times \Bbb R$ multiplies $(0,y)$ into the identity $(1,0)$, so $(0,y)$ doesn't have an inverse.

---

Notation-wise I don't think it's right to say that the inverse of $(x,y)$ is $(x^{-1}, y^{-1})$; I'd write it as $(x,y)^{-1}$.

Comment: Cold number! You've helped me before haven't you?! I'm not sure I understand the relevance of your first comment about inverses and operations (I didn't say I was proving it was an operation but whether or not it is a group), but thank you; the latter part was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Yup, the 16 operations :). With the operation remark I was addressing this: "I know it isn't because not every element will have an inverse"; I thought by that you meant that you thought it wasn't an operation *because* it didn't have inverses, so I thought I'd mention that an operation can be an operation without having inverses. Now I realize you may have meant that $\Bbb R \times \Bbb R$ is not a group with that operation, which is true.

Comment: No no no, I totally see what you mean. Where I said "I'm now looking to determine if the same operation but on \Bbb R \times \Bbb R is an operation" I should have said I'm now looking to determine if the same operation but on \Bbb R \times \Bbb R is a GROUP"

Comment: Yup that makes sense :)